# How to create a module which can be accessed from terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, pypi, python-packaging

I want to create a module that can be accessed from terminal. like how Django is accessed from terminal. with features like Django startadmin startserver etc. how do I do it.I don't want to add "python -m name" to it and it must be just "name".

Answer (score 0):

Look into setting up a console script entry point for your installed package.

There's a good guide over at https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use argparse library to get input through command line.
*1 line is to:* import the library
2 *line is to:* make an object of class ArgumentParser()
*3 line is to:* add arguement
*4 line is to:* store them as a dictionnary

```
import argparse
ap=argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i","--image",required=True,help="path of the image")
args=vars(ap.parse_args())
```